# What statistical technique would be most appropriate for comparing two instructional approaches?

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I work in a school and would like to use a statistical technique for comparing the performance of students using two different instructional programs.

A first grade teacher uses a new, specialized spelling program not used by any other teacher in the school. The following year, a second grade teacher would like to find out if students from the first grade teacher's class are better spellers than students from other classes.

The second grade teacher has fairly small samples. There are 3-5 students in the classroom from the previous first grade teacher's class and 11-13 students from other first grade teachers who didn't use the specialized program.

The teacher would like to evaluate spelling by the number of words correct on a well-recognized 100 word spelling inventory.

Which statistical techniques would be appropriate for helping the teacher determine if the students who did or didn't receive the specialized spelling program are achieving at the same level? Due to the small sample sizes, would it be useful to use a Mann-Whitney U Test?  Are the sample sizes too small to look at the relationship through a Point-Biserial Correlation Coefficient?

Thank you very much for any assistance.

Answer (score 3):

The size of the sample doesn't dictate Mann Whitney vs. some other test; I like @GregSnow's idea of a permutation test. But with this sample size, to find a statistically significant difference, the effect size would have to be huge. In fact, I think they'd have to be so large that I would suspect some sort of other cause.

Comment: For the permutation test the size of the effect does not play as much of a role as how the top scores are distributed between the groups.  For the minimum numbers above of 3 and 11 there are 364 possible unique permutations between the groups which suggests 18 possible combinations that would lead to a significant test (at 0.05).  Clearly if the 3 all did better than the other 11 you would get significance. but if the very best score is in the group of 11 I don't think you could get significance.  But comparing scores of 1-11 vs 98-100 will not be more significant than 39-50 vs. 51-53.

Answer (score 1):

Since the test is a "correct/not correct" decision for each item you could consider the scores to be from a binomial distribution (if the chances of spelling a word correct are equal and independent) and use binomial distributions to compare, possibly through a logistic regression model.

With the small sample sizes and possibility of non-independence, I would look at using a permutation test (the MW U-test is a special case of a permutation test).

But consider that with the data you describe, any difference could be due to the teaching method, the teacher, or a classroom effect (one of the students inspired the others to study harder, or distracted everyone, creating a difference that would not be seen in another class receiving the same method).